# Hashing password longer than 14 characters in wpa_supplicant.conf

Tags: wifi, security

My college has a WPA2 Enterprise network, which I can connect to on my Pi after adding the network in *wpa_supplicant.conf*.

I don't want my Wi-Fi password stored in plain text, so I use `echo -n $password | iconv -t utf16le | openssl md4` to hash it, and then store the MD4 hash instead of the plain text password in the file.

I've helped a lot of students to get their Pis connected to the network, and doing this has always worked, until last night when it wasn't working for someone. It seems like the problem is that their password is longer than 14 characters, which is great for security, but it causes problems with the MD4 hash algorithm.

Is there a way to hash passwords in the *wpa_supplicant.conf* file that are longer than 14 characters? I guess I should try using only the first 14 characters of the password to connect, but if that worked it would seem insecure.

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen the procedure you suggest, but have you tried `wpa_passphrase` as suggested in https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md

This should work for passphrases from 8-63 characters

Storing passwords in `wpa_supplicant.conf` is not really a security risk, as the file is only readable by root.

Comment: `wpa_passphrase` won't work because it generates a PSK for a WPA-PSK network. My school's network is WPA-EAP, which requires a separate username and password, and is why I've been using NTLM password hashing instead.

Comment: this is enterprise wlan, your user/passphrase is often used for a whole lot of important things. If someone steals the hashed pw then they can use the wlan, if someone steals the plain text pw then they can access your email too. The fact that `root` owns it is a false sense of security, you can read it directly off the sd card... Imagine a raspberry pi running a display case, very public

Comment: @crasic Yes, I wrote a Bash script to automatically add the network to `wpa_supplicant.conf` which originally stored the password in plain text, but when I asked the IT department to approve it, they said it should be hashed and I can understand why. When my script stored the password in plain text, I had to help a professor set it up on their machine and ended up seeing their password in the process.